# why when creating e2-small it shows it has 2 vCPU and when checking configuration it shows it has only 1 vCPU

Tags: google-compute-engine, multi-core

- This is why I get when creating a  e2-small machine
  [image]
- This is what I got then checking the machine after creation:
  [image]
- This is what is shown on the page https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing:
  [image]
- This is what I get when using cat /proc/cpuinfo:
  [image]

Which one is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first screenshot, it shows **e2-small** (2 vCPU, 2 GB memory), and 1 shared core under vCPU. **One CPU core** is **2 vCPUs**.

In the second screenshot, it shows **one shared core**, which is mentioned the same
in the first screenshot. Both the first and second screenshots are referring to the same thing.

The **E2 machine series** also contains shared-core machine types that use context- switching to share a physical core between vCPUs for multitasking. Different shared-core machine types sustain different amounts of time on a physical core.

In general, shared-core machine types can be more cost-effective for running small, non-resource intensive applications than standard, high-memory, or high-CPU machine types.

A vCPU is a **multi-thread**. Multithreading is a form of parallelization or dividing up work for simultaneous processing. Instead of giving a large workload to a single core, threaded programs split the work into multiple software threads. These threads are processed in parallel by different CPU cores to save time.

Each CPU core consists of two hyper-threads.

Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#machine_types) for more information on E2 family categories.